# Formatting a string with {} around a specific instance

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, format

I have a function that will create hash verification regex's:

```
import re

def build_re(hex_len, prefix=r"", suffix=r"(:.+)?"):
    regex_string = r"^{}[a-f0-9]{}{}$".format(prefix, hex_len, suffix)
    return re.compile(regex_string, re.IGNORECASE)
```

This function should take the length of a hash (`098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6` for example) and verify it, however when I use this function:

```
md5 = build_re(32)
print md5.match("098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6")
>>> None
len("098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6")
>>> 32
```

It should indeed match a 32 character hash string, and if I do it manually:

```
>>> hash_regex = "^[a-f0-9]{32}(:.+)?$"
>>> test_string = "098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6"
>>> data = re.compile(hash_regex)
>>> data.match(test_string)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02ABB4E0>
>>> if data.match(test_string):
    print "matched"     
matched
```

So I thought maybe it's the prefix that is causing it:

```
>>> def build_re(hex_len, prefix=r"", suffix=r"(:.+)?"):
        regex_string = r"^{}[a-f0-9]{}{}$".format(prefix, hex_len, suffix)
        print regex_string
        return re.compile(regex_string, re.IGNORECASE)

>>> build_re(32)
^[a-f0-9]32(:.+)?$
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x029D89E0>
>>>
```

That didn't prove anything, then I noticed that: `"^[a-f0-9]32(:.+)?$" == "^[a-f0-9]{32}(:.+)?$"` is `False` because the `32` in the function build regex does not have `{}` around it. So my question is this, how can I format a string using the `.format` function and supply curly brackets around a specific instance of that string? If I do try this, I get:

```
>>> def build_re(hex_len, prefix=r"", suffix=r"(:.+)?"):
        regex_string = r"^{}[a-f0-9]{{}}{}$".format(prefix, hex_len, suffix)
        print regex_string
        return re.compile(regex_string, re.IGNORECASE)

>>> build_re(32)
^[a-f0-9]{}32$
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x02A40740>
>>>
```

Can this be done successfully without the use of deprecared `%d` methods?

Comment: Please remove all the unrelated information from your question and shorten it to *"How can I use `.format` on a string that contains curly braces {}?"*.

Comment: @Rawing I'm just showing how I came to the conclusion

Comment: You have a simple question; why inflate it to this monstrous wall of text? How you came to the conclusion is completely irrelevant. It doesn't help us solve your problem, it only forces us to read more and makes your question _harder_ to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use three braces `{{{}}}`. The outer two braces produce literal `{}` in the result, and the inner braces get replaced by `hex_len`.

```
regex_string = r"^{}[a-f0-9]{{{}}}{}$".format(prefix, hex_len, suffix)
```